# NodeJS Express error al intentar obtener usuario por id

Tags: nodejs, express

**Usuario Model**

```
module.exports = function () {

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var db = require('../libs/db-connection.js')();
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    const usuariosSchema = new Schema({
         nombre: String,
         apel_1: String,
         apel_2: String,
         email:String,
         fecha_nacimiento: Date
    });

    return db.model("usuarios",usuariosSchema);
}
```

**usuario.controller**

```
exports.obtener_por_id = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;

  User.findById(id)
    .then(usuario => {

      if (usuario) {
        res.json({
          status: 200,
          usuario: usuario
        }); 
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        status: 404,
        message: "Error al obtener usuario por id",
        error: err
      });
    });

};
```

**usuario.routing**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const usuarios_controller = require('../controllers/user');


router.get('/:id',usuarios_controller.obtener_por_id);



module.exports = router;
```

Añadir que tengo otros **routings** en la misma pagina de **usuario.routing** y me funcnionan **perfectamente** pero cuando añado `router.get('/:id',usuarios_controller.obtener_por_id);` ya no me va nada.

Este es el **error** que me lanza:

```
DATA API =  
{…}
​
error: Object { message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"all\" at path \"_id\" for model \"usuarios\"", name: "CastError", stringValue: "\"all\"", … }
​
message: "Error al obtener usuario por id"
​
status: 404
​
<prototype>: {…
```

**Reitero** que tengo otras funciones en el **usuario.controller** y me va perfectamente, lo unico que me esta fallando es el que me **obtiene un usuario por su ID**

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el orden en que tienes el resto de tus rutas para usuario? Si sólo tienes una ruta que maneja el `id`, ésta debe ir al final de todas tus otras rutas. Verifica eso

Comment: Lo más probable es que estés recibiendo un valor en `id` que no sea un `ObjectId`. Adopta la costumbre de **depurar** tu código para ver exactamente cuál es el contenido del contexto de ejecución, así puedes ver el contenido de parámetros, variables y demás.